# How Java Logical short circuit Operators Work

Tags: java

I wonder how the below code return false.

```
String line ="";
if (line.length() > 0 && !line.startsWith("/*") || !line.startsWith("--")) {    
  return false;
}
```

What I know is if we use &&, execution starts from left and it proceeds only if left result is true, else it do not proceed.

but in the above code its returning false. The value of `line.length()` is 0, but its validating second condition and evaluating to true because the other two conditions are true and returning false.

Help me in understanding this operator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two operators. The AND operator is evaluated first and returns `false`. Then the OR operator is evaluated and returns `true`, since the second operand of the OR operator is true:

```
if (line.length() > 0 && !line.startsWith("/*") || !line.startsWith("--"))
          false       &&      not evaluated
                     false                      ||         true
                                               true
```

If you want the second operand of the AND operator to include the OR operator, you should add parentheses:

```
if (line.length() > 0 && (!line.startsWith("/*") || !line.startsWith("--")))
        false                             not evaluated
                     false
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. What I am telling is if ****line.length()>0**** is failing why its going to validate other things. It should short circuit right? Its should not validate other conditions and it should fail the if test. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Abdul It does short circuit, which is why `!line.startsWith("/*")` is never evaluated, however, `|| !line.startsWith("--")` is not part of the operands of the the AND operator, so after the AND operator is evaluated to false, the OR is evaluated - `(false || !line.startsWith("--")` - returning true.

Comment: Thanks, after adding parentheses part, I understood.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Look at **The conditional operators** section. It says it clearly: the second condition is only evaluated if needed. Since there are no parentheses giving your conditions any hierarchy, it evaluates the first one. length isn't bigger than 0, so it returns false and it doesn't evaluate the other 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you add brackets to your code it will be clearer e.g.

```
if ( (line.length() > 0 && !line.startsWith("/*") ) || !line.startsWith("--"))
```

The first operator `&&` is evaluated to false inside the brackets while the second operator `||` is evaluated to true.

Comment: I know that, I am confused about Java Short circuit operators.

Comment: @Abdul You are not short-circuiting here. There are two different operators working. The left operator will return `false` or `true` and it will compare that value to the right side of  `||`. If you want to short-circuit it you have to use brackets around the statement

Answer (score 0):

First, `line.length() > 0 && !line.startsWith("/*")` is `false`. Then, the evaluation continue to `false || !line.startsWith("--")` which is `true`. That's why the codes inside your if statement block is executed.

From my inference, I think what you really need is :

```
if (line.length() > 0 && (!line.startsWith("/*") || !line.startsWith("--")))
```

That is in which the power of parentheses shows off!